# .htaccess multiple domain redirect to one wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, multiple-domains

Search all internet, try many redirect versions, but no one works for my wordpress site.

Ok! I have 3 domains:

- www.domain1.**lv** (this is a default domain)
- www.domain2.eu (these two are new domains)
- www.domain3.eu

When i go to domain1 it opens http://www.domain1.lv/lat/ (default language page). 
So, when i go to domain2 or domain3 i want that it opens http://www.domain2or3.eu/eng/ (english site version). If it not possible, it can redirect to http:// www.domain1.lv/eng/

At the moment, when i open new links, it redirects to default domain with some strange random page in it..

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your domain 2 or domain 3 htaccess, put

```
     Redirect 301 / http://www.domain2or3.eu/eng/
```

Comment: Yes, this would work. But my domain2 and domain3 have connected to the same directory as domain1. I have 3 domains to one directory/one wordpress installation/one .htaccess.